Looping through two cells with specified ranges
I currently have a loop that iterates through the number of units from 1 to 20. However, I’d like to add a second loop to run concurrently. Specifically, for every multiple in a range (i.e., 10 to 20), I want to loop through the number of units. Could someone help me modify my code to include the multiple loop on top of the unit loop? Thanks for your help!
MAXUNIT = 20
MULTIPLE = the cell that can be set between 10-20 for the multiple
NUMBER = the cell that can be set between 1-20 for the number of units
Sub Calculate()

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

'Loop through multiples (10-20) & number of units (1-20)

Dim i As Integer
Dim A As Integer
Dim B As Integer
Dim Counter As Integer

Range("MULTIPLE").Value = 10

A = 1
B = Range("MAXUNIT").Value
Counter = A
i = A - 1

Do Until i = B

        Range("NUMBER").Value = Counter
        
        i = i + 1
        Counter = Counter + 1
    Loop

Range("NUMBER").Value = 1

End Sub


You can use a nested loop:  For unit = 1 to 20: For mult = 10 to 20:[do something with unit and mult]: Next mult: Next unit

Thanks, Tim! Would you be so kind as to write that out? I would be very grateful!

That's all I could write since it's unclear what it is you're doing above.

Like this, though it's unclear what this is for:
Sub Calculate()
    
    Dim unit As Long, mult As Long 'prefer Long over Integer
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    For unit = 1 To Range("MAXUNIT").Value
        
        Range("NUMBER").Value = unit
        
        For mult = 10 To 20
            Range("MULTIPLE").Value = mult
        Next mult
    
    Next unit
    
    Range("NUMBER").Value = 1

End Sub


Hi Tim,
Thanks again! This solution works perfectly, and I’ve been using it over the past week.
I have a quick follow-up: if I were to work with percentages instead of units, with steps of 0.25% or 0.50% rather than integers, how would I need to rewrite the code?
I’d greatly appreciate your help - thanks!

% are in which loop, unit or mult ?   There's no problem using (eg) For mult = 10 to 20 Step 0.25

In both unit and mult. Great, wasn't aware I can just add Step 0.25 after each. Thanks a lot!

Please flag as "Accepted" if this answered your question, to help out anyone coming along later with a similar problem.

Nesting Loops
Sub UnitsForMultiples()
    
    ' Define constants.
    Const LAST_MULTIPLE As Long = 20
    Const FIRST_UNIT As Long = 1

    ' Reference the worksheet.
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet ' improve!

    ' Retrieve the first multiple.
    Dim FirstMultiple As Long: FirstMultiple = ws.Range("MULTIPLE").Value
    ' Retrieve the last unit.
    Dim LastUnit As Long: LastUnit = ws.Range("MAXUNIT").Value
    
    Dim Multiple As Long, Unit As Long
    
    ' Loop through the multiples...
    For Multiple = FirstMultiple To LAST_MULTIPLE
        ' ... and for each multiple, loop through the units...
        For Unit = FIRST_UNIT To LastUnit
            ' ... copying each unit to the Number cell...
            ws.Range("NUMBER").Value = Unit
            ' Do something 'more' useful, e.g.:
            Debug.Print Multiple, Unit
        Next Unit
    Next Multiple
    
    ' Reset the Number cell.
    ws.Range("NUMBER").Value = 1
    
End Sub

